# Run multiple .dtsx files together

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I have three different *.dtsx* packages under a single ssis package. How to execute all three together with a single click without having to open each dtsx file and execute them separately

Comment: I respect that the OP is free to accept a solution. But i can't understand why unaccepting a solution to accept the same one from another user. Sequence container doesn't make any difference. Anyway, good luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps to execute three different .dtsx packages under a single ssis package.

1. Create a package and drag a sequence container into the package.
2. Inside sequence container Drag and drop three Execute Package Task.
3. Map all three Execute Package Task with respected .dtsx package.
4. Execute the sequence container.

**Execution process:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: why sequence container? it changes nothing in this case

Comment: To Group the two packages into single unit of work i used Sequence container.When you execute the container both the packages would be executed  parallely.

Comment: Without it they would be executed parallely too

Comment: Yes they would execute but it should be recommendation that every task should define inside the container. it depends us how we define tasks inside the control flow.

Comment: It is not necessary to put in a container but is more organized. Things have to be understandable by everyone and a container facilitates it in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

## Suggested Solution

Create a new SSIS package, and in the `Control Flow` add three `Execute Package Task`, and configure each one for a package.

## Additional informations

*"The Execute Package task extends the enterprise capabilities of Integration Services by letting packages run other packages as part of a workflow." [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-package-task)*

## Helpful Links

- [SQL SERVER – The Basics of the Execute Package Task](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/12/sql-server-the-basics-of-the-execute-package-task-notes-from-the-field-067/)
- [Execute Package Task in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/execute-package-task-in-ssis/)